# How to get tuple values in IActionResult net core 2

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, tuples

I have a view with two model.

This is my cshtml code:

```
@model Tuple<FITSWeb.Models.Test, FITSWeb.Models.Resultat>
```

```
<div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Selection du résultat</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="padding:10px">
                <label class="control-label">Démarche</label>
                <textarea readonly rows="3" class="form-control">@Model.Item1.Demarche</textarea>

                <label class="control-label">Jeu d'entrée</label>
                <textarea readonly rows="3" class="form-control">@Model.Item1.JeuEntree</textarea>

                <label class="control-label">Résultat attendu</label>
                <textarea readonly rows="3" class="form-control">@Model.Item1.ResultatAttendu</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Selectionner le résutat retenu pour :
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="padding:10px">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Item2.Commentaire" class="control-label">Commentaire</label>
                <textarea rows="3" asp-for="@Model.Item2.Commentaire" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Item2.Commentaire" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the cs code:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddResult(long id)
    {
        Resultat TResultat = new Resultat();
        var test = await _context.Test.Where(m => m.Id == id).Include(i => i.Resultats).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (test != null)
        {
           TResultat = await _context.Resultat.Where(m => m.Id == test.ResultatRef.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            }
            return PartialView("~/Views/Tests/_Result.cshtml", Tuple.Create<Test, Resultat>(test, TResultat));
        }
        return View();
    }
```

how can i get tuple values for 'test' and 'Tresultat' after submit?

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddResult(long id, [Bind("Numero,Condition,Demarche,JeuEntree,ResultatAttendu,Utilisateur,DateCreation,DateModification,EstActif,Id")] Test test,
                                                        [Bind("IdTest,IdSession,Commentaire,EtatActuel,Utilisateur,DateCreation,Id")] Resultat TResultat)
    {...}
```

This code don't return tuple values, and i don't find the good solution.

Comment: Would it not be easier to create a custom view model to hold this data, and just get that back on the server? I know Tuples had problems with ModelBinding as they dont have a default empty Constructor. How are you getting back your id? As it does not exist on the view?

Comment: As you suggested to me, I created a custom model with the necessary attributes of the two basic models. and it works very well: !! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this(Please note this is only a sample); your "About" csthml page:

```
@model Tuple<M1, M2>

<form asp-action="AddResult">
    <input  name="blah1" value="@Model.Item1.Field1" />
    <input  name="blah2" value="@Model.Item2.Field2" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The backend GET action:

```
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
    var vm = new Tuple<M1, M2>(new M1(), new M2());
    return View(vm);
}
```

The backend POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddResult(MyViewModel o)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(About));
}
```

The models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Blah1 { get; set; }

    public string Blah2 { get; set; }
}

public class M1
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}

public class M2
{
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

In my opinion, you should return only one view model object instead of Tuple in the GET action because it would give you more flexibility and its easier to maintain.